# What command is executed when I click "open as Administrator" in Files from the Dock?

Tags: plank, pantheon-files

When I right click on Files in the Dock, I can chose to open "New Windows As Administrator":

[image]

What command does this execute? Is it `sudo -i pantheon-files`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is `pantheon-files-pkexec`

You can find it in `/usr/share/applications/pantheon-files.desktop`. It looks like this:

```
[Root Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window As _Administrator
Exec=pantheon-files-pkexec
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```